# Call to a member function chunk() on array Laravel Maatwebsite

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to show records via excel file using maatwebsite in laravel. However, I'm getting error below

> Call to a member function chunk() on array

I searched the error and try to apply the resolution in mine but I'm still getting same result. Here's my code

```
    $date_replenishment = $this->date_replenishment;
    $agent_id = $this->agent_id;

    // Get the Branch
    $branches = Branch::where('agent_id', $agent_id)->get();

    foreach($branches as $branch) {

        $branch_id = $branch['id'];

        // Get the Branch
        $get_branch = Branch::where('id', $branch_id)->first();

        $is_sendout_report = $get_branch['is_sendout_report'];

        $matchFields = [
            'transaction_date' => $date_replenishment,
            'branch_id' => $branch_id
        ];

        if ($is_sendout_report == 0) {

            // Without Sendout Value
            $results[] = Recon::groupBy('branch_id')
            ->where($matchFields)
            ->selectRaw('transaction_date')
            ->selectRaw('Round(sum(NetDollarPayOutReplenishment), 2) as NetDollarPayOutReplenishment')
            ->selectRaw('Round(sum(NetShare), 2) as NetShare')
            ->selectRaw('Round(sum(PayPrincipalLOCPayPeso), 2) as NetPesoReplenishmentLOC')
            ->selectRaw('Round(sum(PayPrincipalUSDPayPeso), 2) as NetPesoReplenishmentUSD')
            //  ->selectRaw('sum(ForDeposit) as ForDeposit')
            ->selectRaw('group_account');

        } else {

            // With sendout value
            $results[] = Recon::groupBy('branch_id')
            ->where($matchFields)
            ->selectRaw('transaction_date')
            ->selectRaw('Round(sum(NetDollarPayOutReplenishment), 2) as NetDollarPayOutReplenishment')
            ->selectRaw('Round(sum(NetShare), 2) as NetShare')
            ->selectRaw('Round(sum(NetPesoReplenishmentLOC), 2) as NetPesoReplenishmentLOC')
            ->selectRaw('Round(sum(NetPesoReplenishmentUSD), 2) as NetPesoReplenishmentUSD')
            //  ->selectRaw('sum(ForDeposit) as ForDeposit')
            ->selectRaw('group_account');

        }
    }


    return $results;
```

Sample output if I print the results

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8ydB.png)

Comment: You're not using the `chunk()` method within this code so the error is most likely coming from elsewhere, perhaps the code that uses the resulting `$results`?  Basically that method is only available on a query builder instance, but it seems you're attempting to call it on an array.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is array.

You can convert array to collect.

```
$collection = collect($results);
```

Comment: Your query has not got data. Please add **selectRaw('group_account')-> get() -> toArray();** into the query